# can not set datatable's width of jquery's datatable plugins 10.1

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatable

I have many datatables of jQuery plugin in the page. For some datatables, the with fit with the page, but for others, the datatable's width is more larger than the page. I have tried a lot of things without success:
-set style in html
-use this function of datatables

```
fnInitComplete : function() {
   $("#tableid").css("width","100%");
}
```

. with these method, I have not been able to set it properly and don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

if you table columns are so much to fit in the page width, then you can use datatable responsive plugin example is here

https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/column-control/auto.html

if you table columns are enough to fit in the page then it would take the width automatically, if you are using bootstrap add class in the table tag.
for ex.

```
<table class="table">
   <thead>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

with css use

```
max-width:100%
```

Comment: Hello @Sam, i am using theses stuffs to show details when some user select a specific image of the row. I have also tried to use the class as specified without success.

Comment: have you tried with responsive plugin its pertty good and promising plugin, where you can select which columns to hide in which width etc. or if the case is something different can you provide sample fiddle so i can look into it. :)

Comment: have you added fiddle link? its not visible inside comment.

Comment: not yet, i will just send you the code that i have used

Comment: sam it is written that the code is too long to write it in the comment, please can you tell me how to do?

Comment: i don't have any knowledge about fiddle link

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ go on this link and reproduce your code here you can add external files css, js etc. and just press on share button it will give one link paste that link here

Comment: i known the web site but not the use

Comment: in the code, i get my data with json from the controller (MVC) and send it to the view

Comment: can you add your html as well, otherwise it won't be working.

Comment: data are fetched from the database and due to the use of this plugging, the html is empthy when looking from viewsource

Comment: just track your ajax, where it fetches html, and get it as html.

Comment: i will however post the html code for this datatable

Comment: you will excuse me again, but i don't know how to do this

Comment: I finally solve the problem and also learn some things about datatable: -if you have more than one datatable, each datatable must be contained in a div. By setting the class of these div, you can set the with of the datatable( this class should contain the overflow property to allow the datatable to have a max with that they could not pass). Once that these specific div have been obtained, put them in another div which will contain these individual div, then set the overflow property on this main div class (auto), it will allow you to be sure that there will be an automatic scroller added

Answer (score 0):

Just set table width to 100%

```
<table width="100%">
       <thead>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
       </tbody>
 </table>
```